# In c# , what does it mean '??'?

Tags: c#, symbols

** Please stop to devote this question. I really don't know what to search for it. I have tried to use keyword like 'C# ??' and tried in the title of the qeustion like '?? what it ' but there is no any question in the 'Questions that may already have your answer' box.

```
public ICommand _command;
public ICommand Command
{
    get
    {
        return _command ?? (_command = new MvxCommand(AddItem));
    }
}
```

I found i like those code. But I really don't know what does it mean?

Additional, if i want to search in msdn about it, what the keyword I should use for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called a Null coalescing operator

if the first part is null then use the next part, in your case if `_command` is null then it creates a new `command` else it would use `_command` only

Answer (score 1):

it's Null coalescing operator.  It means if this has a value use it, if not use the next item.

It's very useful for nullable types and objects.

```
int? age = null; 

var defaultAge = age ?? 21;
//defaultAge is now 21
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Null Coalesce operator.  Functions just like, "IsNull" in TSQL.  If the left value is not null, use it.  Otherwise, use the right value.